# Azure DevOps extract unique visitors

Tags: azure-devops

I am running a version of Azure DevOps and would like to track adoption.

Is it possible to get the number of unique visitors who have logged in / used Azure DevOps in the last 30 days, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built-in way but here are two hacks:

You can look at `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_settings/audit` , then set the date range to what you want and manually count.

An automated way of doing that could be to use the [ADO REST API and send a Query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/audit%20log/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the Audit log, then use a bit of code to tally up the unique users from the response.